# How to remove default disclaimer in javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail, smtps

When sending emails via javamail, the following is always appended to the bottom of each message:

> This email and any files transmitted with it are confidential and
>   intended solely for the use of the individual or entity to whom they
>   are addressed. If you have received this email in error please notify
>   the system manager. This message contains confidential information and
>   is intended only for the individual named. If you are not the named
>   addressee you should not disseminate, distribute or copy this e-mail.
>   Please notify the sender immediately by e-mail if you have received
>   this e-mail by mistake and delete this e-mail from your system. If you
>   are not the intended recipient you are notified that disclosing,
>   copying, distributing or taking any action in reliance on the contents
>   of this information is strictly prohibited.

How does one prevent this?

(NOTE: This problem is extremely frustrating to research on the web due to the fact that a disclaimer of this form is attached to so many indexed documents! :-(

Comment: I can assure you that JavaMail plays zero part in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaMail is not doing that, it is your outgoing `SMTP` server appending it to each message, probably set up by IT.

To confirm, you can use gmail's servers (*with a personal account*) and you will see it does not get added to the messages.

Comment: I am using gmail (smtp.gmail.com), and also a member of IT (and not aware of any strange SMTPS config).

Comment: it is most definitely not strange, a lot of companies do this. it is also possible to set up in gmail, for example: http://goo.gl/T4poRi

Comment: Thanks for the lead epoch! Here is where I tracked down the ultimate solution: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Pay attention to the form in which email body get parsed. In my case the emailBody string is on one line, so you have to put the "#Your disclaimer Here#" on one line. Answer for who will come in future.

```
public String deleteDisclaimer(String emailBody) {

                String disclaimer = "#Your disclaimer here#";

                if (emailBody.contains(disclaimer)) {
                    System.out.println("Deleting Disclaimer..");
                    return emailBody.substring(0,emailBody.indexOf(disclaimer));
                }
                System.out.println("DISCLAIMER NOT FOUND!");
                return emailBody;
            }
```